# How to make Read-only MS Access Back End editable again

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a Microsoft Access Back End database that, when opened, shows a "READ-ONLY  This database has been opened read-only. You can only change data in linked tables. To make design changes, save a copy of the database."

[image: Read-only warning]

The Microsoft Access "application" is a split database. The Back End file lives on a network share drive, and all users (are supposed to) have full read-write-delete permissions on that folder. Each user (is supposed to) download a copy of the Front End to their local machine and use their own Front End copy, which links all tables to the Back End file. The Read-only file attribute on the Back End file (via right-click -> Properties) is unchecked.

[image: File properties]

I'm relatively certain that the cause of the problem is that a user that *only* had read permission on the Back End folder downloaded and opened the Front End file, and that Access was unable to create a .laccdb lock file, and handled the situation by marking the Back End itself as read-only somehow.

I've tried making a copy of the Back End file, and while this copy is no longer read-only, there is a file lock, as if someone still has the application open, on the Back End file, so I can't rename or delete the existing Back End file to replace it with the editable copy.

Given all this, how do I tell Access to stop treating the Back End file as read-only?

Comment: In the security center of Access, mark the network folder as a trusted location. Also, use a script to launch the frontend and set the Registry as needed as detailed in my article:  [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D).

Comment: Those are great suggestions, and I'll plan on implementing them - thanks for the script.
However, I don't see anywhere in that article that discusses "unlocking" an already read-only back end. Do you have any solutions for the problem posed in the question?

Comment: That's what the script takes care of. A backend isn't locked - it contains tables only.

Comment: I think someone has managed to open your back end db exclusively, perhaps via the scenario you described where the user has incomplete permissions to the folder.  Reach out to your server support folks to see who has the file open.  They should also be able to disconnect this user.